# Consulta MySQL usando tabelas associativas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Bom, eu estou tento bastante dificuldade em fazer uma consulta no MySQL.

Eu tenho uma tabela que tem relação com outras duas tabelas.
Esta tabela é `anime_genre` ela possui dois campos `foreign key` um chamado `ID_anime` e outro o `ID_genre`.
O campo `ID_anime` faz relação com o `ID` da tabela `anime` e o campo `ID_genre` faz relação o `ID` da tabela `genre`, a tabela `anime` tem os campos `ID` e `name` e a tabela gêneros também possuem os campos `ID` e `name`. Bom, com o uso do `INNER JOIN` eu consigo listar os registros da relação da tabela `anime_genre` com a tabela `genre` e `anime`. Por exemplo, eu tenho as seguintes estruturas:

**anime**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID | name         |
+----+--------------+
| 6  | One Piece    |
+----+--------------+
| 7  | Tower Of God |
+----+--------------+
```

**genre**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID | name         |
+----+--------------+
| 5  | Ação         |
+----+--------------+
| 4  | Aventura     |
+----+--------------+
| 3  | Comédia      |
+----+--------------+
| 2  | Sci-Fi       |
+----+--------------+
```

**anime_genre**

```
+----------+-----------+
| ID_anime | ID_genre  |
+----------+-----------+
| 6        | 5         |
+----------+-----------+
| 6        | 4         |
+----------+-----------+
| 6        | 3         |
+----------+-----------+
| 7        | 5         |
+----------+-----------+
| 7        | 4         |
+----------+-----------+
```

Como dito, com o `INNER JOIN` eu consigo buscar os registros referente ao `gênero (genre)` e ao `anime` correspondentes aos seus `ID's`:

```
SELECT genre.name
FROM genre
INNER JOIN anime_genre ON genre.ID = anime_genre.ID_genre
INNER JOIN anime ON anime.ID = anime_genre.ID_anime
WHERE ID_anime = 6;

+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Ação      |
+-----------+
| Aventura  |
+-----------+
| Comédia   |
+-----------+
```

Portanto, o que eu quero é consultar os registros de gênero que não correspondem com o `ID do anime (ID_anime)`, por exemplo se eu tenho os gêneros `ação, aventura, comédia` para o `ID_anime = 6`, eu gostaria de fazer uma consulta que exibisse todos os gêneros que não correspondem com o `ID_anime = 6`. Como por exemplo o gênero `Sci-Fi` que está faltando.

Para ficar mais claro, eu quero pegar todos os registros da tabela `genre` que não corresponde ao `ID_anime` na tabela `anime_genre`.

Comment: Cara eu tentei de várias formas mas não consegui entender

Comment: Não creio ter entendido o problema, desculpe-me, posts removidos. Tente gerar um exe mplo no sql fiddle e mostre como precisa dos dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT genre.name
FROM genre
INNER JOIN anime_genre ON genre.ID = anime_genre.ID_genre
INNER JOIN anime ON anime.ID = anime_genre.ID_anime
/*subselect para obter os "genres" do id 6 
  NOT IN para fazer a lista inversa */
WHERE ID_genre not in (select anime_genre1.ID_genre 
                       from anime_genre anime_genre1 
                       where anime_genre1.ID_anime = 6);
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

Comment: Essa query não filtra os resultados, ela exibe todos os registros da tabela anime_genre

Comment: Essa query traz todos os gêneros associados a algum anime, a não ser aqueles que possuam associação com o anime de ID 6 (tirando o erro de digitação na última linha). Eu usaria SELECT DISTINCT para não repetir os gêneros.

Comment: Eu quero a lista inversa, como exeplo tem ação (5), aventura (4), comédia (3) que está registrado para o anime com ID 6 na tabela anime_genre, eu queria buscar os resultados que não estão cadastrados para o anime com ID 6, por exemplo o Sci-FI de ID 2, tipo uma busca inversa, no código que eu usei ele traz todos os gêneros cadastrados para um anime eu queria buscar todos os generos que não estão

Comment: Essa resposta faz exatamente isso. Releia meu comentário, ele descreve exatamente o que ela faz. Tem uma condição que talvez não esteja contemplada nos seus dados, que é só trazer gêneros que estejam associados ao algum anime. Na pergunta, você fala que quer o gênero 2 (sci-fi), mas não mostra que exista algum anime cadastrado nesse gênero. Ver teste em: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79cd50/2 @ibrunoDIE

Comment: Grato , o erro foi que a edição foi no notepad , este tipo de problema é interessante para estes casos de negação , não comprou, não pagou etc.